# How to write return type of class instance in function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-typing

I am loading modules dynamically and I want a type hint for the return type of the below function:

```py
def get_cls_instance_dynamically(website_name: str):
    ''' returns an instance of a class based on website name'''
    
    # Ignore below 2 lines of code if unable to understand. It just returns module
    # e.g. from websites import google (Here 'google' will be dynamically loaded)
    website_class_name = website_name.title()

    website_module = __import__(f"websites.{website_name}", fromlist=[website_class_name])

    website_cls = getattr(website_module, website_class_name)
    return website_cls()
```

Directory Structure:

```
websites
 |- google.py   # contains class 'Google'
 |- twitter.py  # contains class 'Twitter'
```

My problem is How can I define the return type for `get_cls_instance_dynamically` class. Each website class may have different methods.

Usage:
If i use `get_cls_instance_dynamically('google')` then it should return instance of `Google` class present in `templates/google.py` with type hint.

Regards.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: Do `websites.google.Google` and `webstites.twitter.Twitter` share a base class?

Comment: @deceze I guess for that I have to import the modules right? If yes, then my first priority is not loading the classes which are not required. I might have more other classes in the future.

Will I be able to achieve this? Do you have any code snippets?

Regards.

Comment: @Blckknght But in base classes, I won't able to add the methods which aren't present in a specific class. I won't have the same methods & properties in all classes.

Will I be still able to resolve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to give a useful type hint to a function who's return type is determined at runtime.

A context where it can make sense is where several types share a common API, and so you can call the methods in that API on any of them without actually caring what the specific type of the current object is. If this is the situation with your various `websites.foo.Foo` objects, then you should make the type hint indicate the shared API. That could be a common base class (e.g. a `Website` class of some kind), or perhaps a `typing.Protocol` that you define right along side your function (if your type checker supports [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/)).

If there is no common API however, I'd suggest not hinting the return type at all. Calling code will need to know in advance what type it is going to get for a given in put string, and so it can put its own type hints on the variables it stores the return value in:

```
my_goog: websites.google.Google = get_cls_instance_dynamically('google')
my_goog.some_google_specific_method()
```

Of course, this may suggest that a dynamic object creation function will not be very useful, since if the code needs to knows what type of object it wants to create, it could just create the right kind of object itself (e.g. with `my_goog = websites.google.Google()`) rather than calling the function.